# Batch file to run latexdiff

Tags: latexdiff

If you have experience using `latexdiff`, you may know that it depends on `Perl` and the command is `latexdiff draft.tex revision.tex > diff.tex` Yet, every time I need to open up a Windows cmd console and type the command, which bores me. So I wrote a batch file to run it, i.e. write the aforementioned command into a `.bat` file, click it. However, the command executed become as follows, where you can find there was `1` added before `>` and the error information.

Why and How to solve it?

[image]

Comment: What happens if you run the exact command, as you wrote it, in the cmd console, in the given directory? This shouldn't work either, you're command seems to be right (you don't need the `1` in front of `>` in your batch)